# How to convert this ERB to the Slim template language?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, erb, slim-lang

I'm using the Slim template language (http://slim-lang.com/).

Can someone please tell me how to convert this ERB to be used in a friends.html.slim template?

data/people.yaml

```
friends:
  - Tom
  - Dick
  - Harry
```

ERB

```
<ol>
  <% data.people.friends.each do |f| %>
  <li><%= f %></li>
  <% end %>
</ol>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

More a question than an answer, because I'm sort-of assuming you already did this:

```
ol
  - for f in data.people.friends do
    li = f
```

If that didn't work, please describe what you *did* try, and what didn't work.

Comment: That was all I needed. THANKS!

Comment: @maletor I followed the examples from the Slim site for consistency.